# Change DPI of login screen

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

Any way of changing the login screen DPI, as mine is locked at 125% and I would like it to be 100%.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open Regedit (Start, run then type regedit) then navigate to `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop` and add a DWORD value (right click, new, DWORD Value). Call it LogPixels and set the base to decimal.

Now, You can insert a DPI (96=+) into the value field for the corresponding DPI. The DPI is not a percentage. As reference:
96 DPI is 100%
120 DPI is 125%
144 DPI is 150%

It is best to use one of those DPI settings since Windows is tailored to work best with them.

Comment: My HP Envy 17 was annoyingly set at 100 DPI for this setting. Thanks for the tip!